# How to fix "Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in" in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I tried to activate the plugin but it returns this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Here is the code:

```
/**
* Creates a main table
*/
function __naffCreateTable() {
    $rs = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$this->naff_table'");
    $exists = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    if (!$exists) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $this->naff_table . " (
                    link_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,            parent_id int(11),
                    link_name text,                                     link_dest text NOT NULL,
                    link_cute text NOT NULL,                            link_group text,
                    cloak enum('0','1') NOT NULL,                       cloak_title varchar(250),
                    link_raw_clicks int(11) NOT NULL default '0',       link_unique_clicks int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
                    show_in_editor enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '1',  link_keywords enum('0','1'),
                    keywords text,                                      modify_status_txt enum('0','1'),
                    status_txt_type tinyint(2),                         status_txt_custom varchar(200),
                    overwrite_global enum('0','1'),                     overwrite_in_new_win enum('0','1'),
                    overwrite_nofollow enum('0','1'), link_expire varchar(20) , alternate_url text, link_note text ,             link_status enum('0','1') default '1', cookie_prefix varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'mbpni',
                    PRIMARY KEY (`link_id`)
                    );
                    ";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not post your code on stackoverflow?

Comment: Did you mean the full code?

Comment: No, I guess the sample included now should be enough.

Comment: your code will generate the warning if the this->naff tables is not already created, you should check if `mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$this->naff_table'")` returns false (or true which it will return for write type operations) before trying to pass in the result to mysql_fetch_row. Both functions are actually depreicated as well, google mysqli for the replacement versions. ps you are running the code above as part of a class?

Comment: Yep. Part of class only